# How to get audio file info (album, artist, image, ...) Android?

Tags: java, android, mp3

i want to know if i can get mp3 file info like album name, artist, image stored in the mp3 file and more?
if there an way to do this please help.
by the way: i founded a Java library called Entagged but i can't use it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Problem solved by using MediaMetadataRetriever.

```
MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = (MediaMetadataRetriever) new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        Uri uri = (Uri) Uri.fromFile(mp3File);
        mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(MainActivity.this, uri);
        String title = (String) mediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

[jd3lib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jd3lib/) is a Java library that handles MP3s, and their tags. Probably a useful starting point.